# Passing a pointer based struct to cuda

Tags: pointers, struct, cuda

I have C code which uses a pointer to a `struct`. I'm trying to figure out how to pass it to cuda without much luck.

I have

```
typedef struct node {        /* describes a tip species or an ancestor */
  struct node *next, *back;  /* pointers to nodes                      */
 etc...
} node;
```

Then

```
typedef node **pointptr;
static pointptr treenode;
```

In my code I iterate through all of these, and I'm trying to figure out how to pass them to the kernel so I can perform the following operation:

```
for (i = 1; i <= nonodes; i++) {
    treenode[i - 1]->back = NULL;
    etc....
}
```

But I can't figure out how to pass it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in order to use your tree inside the kernel, your `next` and `back` should probably point somewhere in device memory. Assuming you construct your tree on the host and then pass it, you could do something like:

```
node* traverse(node*n){
    if (n==NULL)
        return NULL;

    node x, *d;
    x.back = traverse(n->back);
    x.next = traverse(n->next);
    cudaMalloc(&d, sizeof(node));
    cudaMemcpy(d, &x, sizeof(node), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    return d;
}
```

and by calling it on the root you'd end up with a pointer to the root of the tree in device memory, which you could pass to your kernel directly. I haven't tested this code, and you'd have to write something similar to delete the tree afterwards.

Alternatively, you could store your tree nodes contiguously inside an array, with indices in the `back` and `next` instead of pointers (possibly changing them back to pointers in device code if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Check this question:

[Copying a multi-branch tree to GPU memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336992/copying-a-multi-branch-tree-to-gpu-memory/6340846)

Although it does not answer your question *exactly*, I think it may clear some things out and ultimately help you tackle your problem.